# Am I allowed to bring a drone to Kansai, Japan?

Tags: japan, drones

I'm going to Japan and planning to bring a drone with me. However, I'm worried that my drone is going to be confiscated at the airport.

Are there any rules for bringing a drone into Kansai, Japan?